# Hanged listSelector in ListView

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, scroll, scrollview

I am implementing `ListView` with `android:listSelector`

```
<style name="ListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Selecting works fine, but when I start scrolling, `listSelector` will randomly hang to top or bottom of `ListView`. I would appreciate any help.

[image: Hanged listSelector]

Comment: Is my answer is helpful to you or not?

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697055/android-listselector-still-partly-visible-when-the-item-is-scrolled-out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using a solid color instead of using Drawables. It is a drawback in the layout framework that if you set the solid colors, then the problem of hold occurs.

The code which you are using as :

```
<item name="android:listSelector">@color/red</item>
```

should be used as :

```
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_view_selector</item>
```

The above written drawable should be enclosed in the selector tag.

Here is the code for the list_view_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected" />

</selector>
```

Note : You cannot use the solid color as it is. You have to make the selectors for the each color tone as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#ff0000"
        android:endColor="#ff0000"
        android:startColor="#ff0000" />

</shape>
```

I have checked this at my end. Working Perfect!!

Comment: I have the this problem even with this solution... and the ListView data also scrolls under the selector...

Comment: I also have this problem even with this solution. I have normal state item in selector which hangs in the list.