# ListView listSelector not hiding

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-drawable

I have a ListView with a `listSelector` drawable to indicate the selected item.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/roadSignListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listview" >
</ListView>
```

The `drawable/listview` is a selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/light_gray" />
</selector>
```

Where `light_gray` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#cccccc"
        android:endColor="#cccccc"
        android:startColor="#cccccc" />    
</shape>
```

This is done with the help of the answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755088/hanged-listselector-in-listview).

My problem is the same as in the other question: the background is hanging behind. The provided solution which I'm using at the moment, doesn't work. It is the same problem with using a color directly

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/roadSignListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="#cccccc" >
</ListView>
```

I have set the minimum required API level to 14 and I'm targeting the newest, 19. I'm testing on the new Nexus 7 which is running Android 4.4.2.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Please define states for your drawable like `state_pressed` etc .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
         android:drawable="#333333" />

    <item 
        android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="#334455"/>
   <item 
      android:drawable="#334455"/>



</selector>
```

Comment: why? The last item is used by default if no other match is found before. hence in this case, the only item, without state, should totally work correctly.

Comment: @njzk2 you don't know how much time I was struggeling with my listSelector (a week+) and the solution was SOOOO simple, I had to move the item that has no state from being the 1st to being the last. I don't know how it works for others, as in almost all examples on the net it is the 1st

Comment: @Gavriel: weird. this is a statelistdrawable (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)  and the docs states `the state list is traversed top to bottom and the first item that matches the current state is used`

Comment: @njzk2, it makes perfect sense (now, that I know :), see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214144/how-to-make-custom-listselector-on-custom-listview, it is not exactly because of what you said here, but this made me understand that changing the order might fix it, and it did