# How to make custom listSelector on custom listView

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a custom listSelector to my listView. The code is more-or-less copy&paste from solutions that worked for others in stackoverflow, but it doesn't work for me.

When I turn on the CAB mode, then I can select and deselect the items, and I see the number of selected items in the CAB navbar, but I don't see any indication in the list. I would like to see which items are selected. Any idea why it doesn't work?

layout/category_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/categories_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/category_browser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            tools:listitem="@layout/category_list_item" >
    </ListView>
    <include layout="@layout/ad"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout/category_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.fletech.smartbaby.api.CheckableLinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/category_browser_list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/category_item_icon"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_browser_list_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        tools:text="Category name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        <include layout="@layout/category_features"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            />

        <include layout="@layout/category_status"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            />
</com.fletech.smartbaby.api.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

drawable/list_selector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#40777777"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_long_pressable="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#400000ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checkable="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#400000ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#800000ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and CheckableLinearLayout.java:

```
package com.fletech.smartbaby.api;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
//import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat; // do I need this? I can't see any difference
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    private static final String TAG = CheckableLinearLayout.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_checked};

    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        Log.v(TAG, "setChecked: " + checked);
        if (mChecked != checked) {
            mChecked = checked;
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        Log.v(TAG, "toggle: " + mChecked + " -> " + (!mChecked));
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    // not sure if needed, as it seems to work without this as well
    public boolean performClick() {
        Log.v(TAG, "performClick");
        toggle();
        return super.performClick();
    }

    @Override
    // this might be unnecessary
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        Log.v(TAG, "drawableStateChanged");
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        final Drawable drawable=getBackground();
        if(drawable!=null)
        {
            final int[] myDrawableState=getDrawableState();
            drawable.setState(myDrawableState);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreateDrawableState: " + extraSpace);
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }

        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        SavedState result = new SavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState());
        result.checked = mChecked;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }

        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());

        setChecked(ss.checked);
    }

    protected static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        protected boolean checked;

        protected SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeInt(checked ? 1 : 0);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            checked = in.readInt() == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: CAB mode??? CAB navbar??

Comment: CAB = Contextual Action Bar: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took me more than a week to find out why this thing that works for everyone doesn't work for me. The answer is simple. I hope it'll help others.

The solution was to change the order of the items in the selector xml. The item without any states has to be the last one:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_long_pressable="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#400000ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checkable="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#400000ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#800000ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- the item without any states has to be the last: -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#40777777"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The reason is that it seems that the parser looks for the 1st item in the xml file that matches. It means that if you have items with different number of states, then you should always have those that have more states defined in the top of the xml. For example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checkable="true" android:state_long_pressable="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffff00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_long_pressable="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checkable="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00ff00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#40777777"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

This way, and only this way, you'll see a different color on items that are:
- both checkable and long_pressable
- checkable, but not long_pressable
- long_pressable but not checkable
- everything else

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped me out and did the thing. The order of the items was wrong