# Selector drawable strange behavior: why does it get stuck in the middle of the screen?

Tags: android, listview, selector, drawable

I've tried several combinations of selectors, but the end result is the same. Even though the selector is displayed correctly, if I go up or down the selector stays in the middle of the screen. [It's exactly this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755088/hanged-listselector-in-listview), but I couldn't make it work with this or any other solutions I've found.

Here I am selecting a row:

[image]

And then scrolling down:

[image]

My ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cardListView"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_view_selector"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

My list_view_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected" />
</selector>
```

And my background_selected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#ffffff"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

Thanks in advance.